# How can I export contextily-geopandas image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas, contextily

I have a script where I'm looping through geopandas daraframe and showing each row on a notebook with contextily for basemap, but I'm not sure how can I export it.

I'm aware of the method **bounds2img** but the problem is there I can only export basemap, not my geometry on it.

my code for **add_basemap** is as follows
[image]

Comment: that is a matplotlib figure. many questions on this site on saving matplotlib figures